# Afdding HTML elements to zend navigation

Tags: zend-framework, nav

So I wrote a class as such:

```
class Users_Navigation_Page_Notification extends Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc{

    public function setLabel($label){
        if(substr($label, 0 , 1) == ':'){
            $label = 'Notification';
        }

        return parent::setLabel($label);
    }
}
```

And if I try something like:

```
$label = 'Notification' . '<span>test</span>';
```

It echo's out Notificationtest

which it shouldn't.

How do I make it render HTML elements out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering navigations, the view helper is hardcoded to escape the label of each navigation page which by default uses `htmlspecialchars`.  This would effectively disable HTML since the tags are replaced with HTML entities.

You can try to cheat a bit and change the escaping mechanism prior to outputting your navigation:

```
$view->setEscape('trim'); // will allow html and remove escaping
echo $view->navigation()->menu(); // output navigation
$view->setEscape('htmlspecialchars'); // restore escaping mechanism
```

In the above code, you can change `$view` to `$this` if you are within a view script.

Comment: So this is the right answer for sure, except one issue:

I don't see my <span>test</span> in the source, at all. where as before it was escaping the html and printing it (html and all) to the screen in raw form, now it doesn't do that. I don't see test, just the word notification.

Comment: That's strange that its just gone now.  You may need to post more code, this method/hack works fine when I test with standard Zend_Navigation.

Answer (score -1):

Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/32823280/3684315 suggests using `escapeLabels(false)` function to disable escaping, which seems like a nicer solution.

`<?= $this->navigation()->menu()->escapeLabels(false) ?>`